# Can you read additional data strings from Web API POST which are not in the data model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, dbgeography

In Entity Framework I have a DBGeography object:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
...
public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
```

As I haven't discovered a better way to send a `POINT` object over JSON, I'm intending to send 'lat' and 'lng' string values from my Javascript code and use them on the server during the POST method:

[image: Screenshot from POSTMan REST client]

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostI4Item(myEntity item)
        {
          var lat = (VALUE TO BE SOURCED);
          var lng = (VALUE TO BE SOURCED);
          string Point = String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", lat, lng);
          item.Location = DbGeography.PointFromText(Point, 4326);
          myEntity current = await InsertAsync(item);
          return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }
```

The problem is I don't know how to retrieve values sent to POST that are not expected within the data model.  `item.Location` is accessible because it has been declared.  But, even if I am sending extra key/value pairs in the body of 'lat' and 'lng', **how can I discover those values in code**?  I can't use `item.lat` and `item.lng` as they are not declared, and I don't want extra DB columns for those values... I only want them accepted as input, but not saved.

Is there a method in the data model where I can declare a value (perhaps something read-only or internal) which is expected on the request and available for use within the POST method, but is not actually being saved to my database?

Comment: I had found this answer and believed it might have initially solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792793/post-dbgeography-data-type-in-odata-v4-api but I soon realised, upon refreshing the database, that it was just creating additional columns for latitude and longitude... something I'm hoping to avoid by only storing the DBGeography value after computing the Point() object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35982194/3026149 from Mohamed Badr & Niels R, and this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18215561/3026149 from haim770 are what have solved my problem.

I was unaware that there was a `[NotMapped]` attribute available for my data model, meaning I could expect values of lat & lng without having them create database columns in Entity Framework.

So my class becomes:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
...
public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public double lng { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public double lat { get; set; }
```

And my code becomes:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostI4Item(myEntity item)
        {
          var Point = DbGeography.FromText($"POINT({item.lng} {item.lat})");
          item.Location = Point;
          myEntity current = await InsertAsync(item);
          return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }
```